# Using waterfall inside a function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to download a number of images and do some logic on them.
problem is that I can't rap the entire function inside of waterfall beacuse it is part of an external modoule.

the principle is:

```
function asyncGetImage(link, onResp){
    request({url: link, encoding: null}, function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            var base64prefix = 'data:' + res.headers['content-type'] + ';base64,';
            var image = body.toString('base64');
            onSuccess(image, base64prefix);
        } else {
            console.log("errororororor");
            onResp(null,null);
        }
    });
}
 function getBase64Images (urlArray){
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                var responses = {};
                var respCount = 0;
                urlArray.forEach(function (item){
                    asyncGetImage(item.url,function (image,base64prefix){
                        responses[item.key] = {image:base64prefix+image,ratio: item.ratio};
                        respCount+=1;
                        if (urlArray.length === respCount) {
                            callback(null,responses);
                        }
                    });
                });

            }
        ],
            function(err,response){
                if(err){
                    console.log("ereprwertwertwerter");
                }
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }
        );
    }

function applyLogic(urlList){
    // do some code here
    return getBase64Images(imageUrls);

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of bugs in your code, yes, but what is your problem with `waterfall` and something "*being part of an external module*"?

Comment: problem is that the main funciton , applyLogic is being called inside a forEach loop, htat means that it doesn't wait for the callback to return, not sure about bugs , this code runs fine on its own

Comment: If this is not the problem, you should show us the main function with the problem instead. Probably you should swap `forEach` for its [async counterpart](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), or use `async.map`